# jQuery only apply to current li

Tags: jquery, this

I want to slide toggle the second level ul when I mouse over the relevant first level li.

Currently the script displays all secondary ul on a mouseover.

```
<div id="subNav">
<ul>
   <li>One</li>
       <ul>
           <li>SubOne</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>
       <ul>
           <li>SubTwo</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery

```
$("#sideNav ul li").hover(
        function(){
            $('#sideNav ul li ul').slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            $('#sideNav ul li ul').slideUp();
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to target with `$(this)` inside the function.

```
$("#subNav>ul>li").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
    }
);
```

Note: The above will work from the root ul's only. I assume that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(this).find('ul')
```

I haven't tested this.

HTH